# Нужна ли в этом предложении запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

В отличие от него(,) он отправлен в крепость за "смертоубийство".

Comment: _В отличие **от него(,) он**_  === Коряво! Одно из местоимений надо заменить существительным.

Answer (score 2):

**В ОТЛИЧИЕ ОТ (кого, чего), *предлог***
Обороты, присоединяемые предлогом **"в отличие от"** *могут* обособляться.
О факторах, влияющих на расстановку знаков препинания, можно посмотреть [**здесь**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach1).

*Нашлись и среди нас такие, которые утверждали, что наш профессор **, в отличие** **от прочих навигаторов,** сам никогда не выходил в море.*
А. Некрасов, Приключения капитана Врунгеля.

*Но штормовой ветер **, в отличие от моря,** разводит волну в заливе как бы с большой натугой.* К. Паустовский, Кара-Бугаз.

*Человек **в отличие от животных** приобрел могучее мышление и воображение.*
И. Ефремов, Лезвие бритвы.

*Маршрутники **в отличие от фланеров** ведут визуальное наблюдение преимущественно в пути, при проезде в поездах и эшелонах.* 
В. Богомолов, Момент истины.

*Достаточно надавить пальцем на глазное яблоко, и все реальные предметы **– в** **отличие от галлюцинаций –** раздвоятся.* А. и Б. Стругацкие, Понедельник начинается в субботу.

*…Наша космическая наука преимущественно исследует обратную сторону Луны **, в** **отличие от приземляющихся на дневной стороне американцев.***
В. Пелевин, Омон Ра.

Для того, чтобы понять - нужна запятая или нет? - желателен контекст и замена, как сказал *slava1947*, одного местоимения существительным. Лично я бы поставила запятую.
Вот очень похожие предложения:

***В отличие от него, некоторые*** из авторов только что принятого проекта резолюции систематически не выполняют свои обязанности...
***В отличие от него, Бор*** был убеждённым теоретиком.
***В отличие от него, Франсуа Миттеран*** смог убедить французов только в том, что...

Answer (score 0):

Запятая в этом предложении *факультативна*, то есть ее можно либо ставить, либо нет.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно: **В отличие от него (Гринева)**, он отправлен в крепость за "смертоубийство.

Здесь делается обязательная пауза и ставится запятая, оборот не вписывается в  предложение, не читается без паузы. Таким образом, обособление оборота задает структура предложения.

Пояснение

**Обособление оборота В ОТЛИЧИЕ ОТ  факультативно, но отнюдь не произвольно.** Оборот чаще обособляется, особенно в середине предложения, но позиция оборота – это не самый главный фактор.

Необособленный (обычно нераспространенный) оборот входит в состав предложения и произносится без паузы, то есть встроен в его структуру, его не всегда можно изъять из предложения.

А вот обособленный оборот – это попутное замечание или аналог придаточного сопоставительного. Поэтому не так просто  разобраться с этим оборотом, хотя  достаточно часто допустимы оба варианта.

**Примеры необособленных оборотов (нераспространенные обороты, нет паузы)**.

**В отличие от него** она защищает не Истину от фантомов, а фантомы от Истины [Ирина Новикова. «Октябрь», 2003].

**В отличие от него** Антон, в сущности мальчишка, один тянул дела отцовской лавки в Таганроге, помогал семье и смог окончить гимназию. [Дмитрий Капустин.  2009].

Его белая поверхность играет роль обычного экрана, но **в отличие от него** чувствительна к нажатию (сенсорная доска). [Д. Усенков.  2007]

Comment: Нет в правилах пунктуации такого понятия, "обязательная пауза".